# How to continue a loop while being in a nested loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using a loop and a nested loop, and i need the outer loop to stop whenever the second reaches a certain value.

```
for first in range(0,10):
  for second in range(0,10):
    print(first + second)
```

But i want it to skip to the next 'first' value if the second value is odd.

I tried to do something like this:

```
odd = [1,3,5,7,9]
  for first in range(0,10):
    for second in range(0.10):
      if second in odd:
  continue
```

But it won't work.

Comment: You should use `break` instead of `continue`, using continue would just increment the `second` and your loop of second would continue.

Comment: you have a condition that makes first depend on second, so why are they in that order? wouldnt "second" in the outer loop make more sense ?

Answer (score 0):

`break` breaks out of the inner loop only, which jumps to the after the inner loop. Assuming that there’s no code immediately after the inner loop, then the current iteration of the outer loop will end and the next one will start.

So I think using `break` instead of `continue` should do exactly what you want.

Comment: can you show me an example? i can't figure out how to do it... i want it to do first + second only if second is even, but do it for every number

Comment: the `break` must be indented from the `if ...` expression so it will be actioned Also you have used `range(0.10)` instead of `(0,10)`

Answer (score 0):

To terminate a loop you should use break. Try using break instead of continue